# JodaTime and BeanPropertySqlParameterSource

Tags: spring, postgresql, datetime, jodatime, spring-jdbc

The situation is something like this:

PostgreSQL Database table has a field `dateAdded` which is `timestamp`

The Pojo Model object maps this field as

```
class MyModel{
   org.joda.time.DateTime dateAdded;

}
```

My Dao Implementation is in Spring JDBC Template and it goes as:

```
SqlParameterSource parameters = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(patient);
jdbcInsert.execute(parameters);
```

I read model from the client and build the object using `@Model`. Everything is fine so far. When I execute this, the database throws an exception saying:
<sub>[Edit Erwin]: Turns out the exception is not coming from the database.</sub>

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp : 2011-10-10T21:55:19.790+03:00
```

I don't want to do the formatting manually by implementing a full INSERT statement as there are many fields involved.

What is the best possible solution here? Is there a way to configure `toString()` of `DateTime` on all calls. I also thought about creating an inherited class from DateTime but ... mmhh.. it's a final.

--

### Edit

Per Erwin, I tested DateTime value '2011-10-10T21:55:19.790+03:00' by inserting into a dummy table and it's working. But can't get to work with JDBC. Something related to the JDBC driver?

Comment: '2011-10-10T21:55:19.790+03:00' is valid for a timestamp in all versions of PostgreSQL I know. What is your version? Can it be, that the **single quotes** around the timestamp (that I added here) are missing in your SQL statement? If that's not it, can you show us the corresponding postgresql server log, this would clear the confusion.

Comment: Postgres 9. Thing is that, I'm not writing SQL Insert statement here. I'm simply Building the model object, wrap it using BeanPropertySqlParameterSource, and pushing it to Spring JDBC SimpleJdbcInsert object. This will internally take care of the SQL INSERTS. And you are right. I just tested the same value using a dummy table and it's working. This is totally strange.

Comment: Erwin, Took a while to find Pgsql server log. There is no error message being logged out of this action.

Comment: Can't help you with the JDBC part, my expertise lies with postgresql. If JDBC is just wrong about the syntax, you could work around the problem by providing alternative syntax like `'2011-10-10 21:55:19.790+03:00'`. The `T`, while being perfectly legal is unusual.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Hope somebody else has an answer. As you said, I feel it strange too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is that `JdbcTemplate` is using a prepared statement and then binding the values.  The field in question is a of type timestamp - so it needs to be set as a `java.sql.Date`.  In this case spring is calling the generic `setObject` method passing it the Joda Time `DateTime` instance.  The driver doesn't know how to convert this into a `java.sql.Date` - hence the error.

To fix this problem you can extend `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource` override the `getValue` method. If the type of object is `joda.time.DateTime` convert it to a `java.util.Date` object and return it.  That should fix the issue.

```
class CustomBeanPropertySqlParameterSource extends BeanPropertySqlParameterSource {
  @Override
  Object getValue(String paramName) {
     Object result = super.getValue(paramName);
     if (result instanceof DateTime) {
        return ((DateTime) result).toDate();
     } else {
        return result;
     }
  }
}
```